# Python Rearrange & remove character from html page title

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm running Python 2.7.11 | on Windows 10 using beautifulsoup4 and lxml.

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.daisuki.net/us/en/anime/watch.GUNDAMUNICORNRE0096.13142.html"), "lxml")
Name = soup.title.string

print(Name.replace('#', ""))
```

Output:

01 DEPARTURE 0096 - MOBILE SUIT GUNDAM UNICORN RE:0096 - DAISUKI

Desired Output:

MOBILE SUIT GUNDAM UNICORN RE:0096 - 01 DEPARTURE 0096

How would I go about removing the "- DAISUKI" at the end and re order the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by `-` and rearrange parts of the title:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.daisuki.net/us/en/anime/watch.GUNDAMUNICORNRE0096.13142.html"), "lxml")
>>> Name = soup.title.string
>>> 
>>> " - ".join(Name.replace('#', "").split(" - ")[1::-1])
u'MOBILE SUIT GUNDAM UNICORN RE:0096 - 01 DEPARTURE 0096'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hacky solution incoming:

```
Name = "01 DEPARTURE 0096 - MOBILE SUIT GUNDAM UNICORN RE:0096 - DAISUKI"
print ("- ".join(reversed(Name.split('-')[:2]))).strip()
```